# Getting location in Webview without showing domain

Tags: android, ios, html, webview, geolocation

I have a webview app in both IOS and Android.
Both apps have location permission. When I request the location it says "*mydomain* wants to know your location"

The problem is my domain is an IP:Port. I think it scares people when they see that list of numbers wanting to know your location. Is there anyway to use my app name in webview when requesting location through html/javascript

I understand there are probably security issues with trying to mask who is requesting the location, but thought I would ask.

If the app already has the permission, can I hide the webview location request. 
When the app loads it asks for location, then it asks again right after the site loads.

Comment: No, because it isn't your app that is requesting location access, it is the web page. The user needs to know what location access they are granting.

Comment: Is there a way to override the html location request window if the app has already requested access?

Comment: No, because it isn't the app requesting access. Providing your location to a web site is a different thing to providing your location to an app

Comment: This worked like a charm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820666/how-can-i-send-data-from-swift-to-javascript-and-display-them-in-my-web-view